# Add relative time to timestamp that results in same date?

Tags: php, datetime, time

```
// to simplify $timestamp in this example is the unix timestamp of 2016-04-20
```

Consider this example:

```
strtotime('+1 year', $timestamp); // this returns 2017-04-19
```

How can I make it return `2017-04-20`?

Another example:

```
strtotime('+1 month', $timestamp); // this returns 2016-05-19
```

How can I make it return `2016-05-20`?

Basically, I want to relatively add time that ends up with the same date.

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('+1 day', strtotime('+1 year', $timestamp));
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("Y",$timestamp) + 1 //gives you the next year

$date .= "-" . date("m-d",$timestamp) //concantenates on the current month and day
```

Comment: Essentially, use the date formula to break the time stamp into it's individual date parts and then reassemble the date after adding the relative time to the pertinent date parts.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding what you're asking but you're probably better of using the `DateTime` library built into PHP, it's a lot more flexible than the standard `date()` function.

So you could do:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify('+1 year');

echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); // Outputs: 2017-04-20
```

If you want to create a `DateTime` object from a specific date you can do so by:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-01');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); // Outputs 2016-01-01
```

I believe that's what you're after, it's much cleaner than `date()` and easier to read in my personal opinion.